# Draw line below frame title in beamer

Tags: beamer, rules

How can I draw a line just below the title of the frame using the `beamer` class? I want a clear separation between the title of the frame and the content of the frame. Also, I want the `block` environment to be shaded in blue. The LaTeX code I'm using is

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\mode<beamer>{%
\usetheme[hideothersubsections,
right,width=22mm]{Goettingen}
 }
\title{Math}
\author[Mister X]{X}
\institute{University}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=20mm]{USTL}}
\date{January 15, 2012}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<handout:0>
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{part 1}
 The following proposition is easy to prove.
\begin{block}{Proposition}
 some statement
 \end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do it with TikZ, referring to the current page node:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\topline}{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] {%
    \draw[blue] ([yshift=-1cm]current page.north west)
             -- ([yshift=-1cm,xshift=\paperwidth]current page.north west);}}
...
\begin{frame}\frametitle{part 1}
  \topline
  ...
\end{frame}
```

[image: line in frame]

Comment: Nice, but it would be nice if I could define a command which does that. Also, the the proposition environment does not look good.

Comment: I made it to a command for you. Please don't mix different questions. It would be good if you post another question for a different problem, such as shaded blocks. That's better for a question & answer site.